# GPU Version, Renderer, Vendor in Android

Tags: android, version, gpu, renderer, vendor

I want to find GPU Vendor, its version and renderer.
I have used this code:-

```
 renderer = GLES10.glGetString(GL10.GL_RENDERER);           
 vendor = GLES10.glGetString(GL10.GL_VENDOR);
 version = GLES10.glGetString(GL10.GL_VERSION);
```

works on Android 4.3 and above, but when I ran this code on Android 2.3.6 it returns null.

However, the check following code check the GPUVersion which is returning "2.0"  with 2.3.6:-

```
final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();               
    GPUVersion = configurationInfo.getGlEsVersion();
```

but still the above 3 lines returns null.

Is there any way to get the above information for all the devices.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the only way to get a value across different Android versions is to split methods depending on which version you are running. You can do something like:

```
public static String getGlVersion(Context ctx) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = am.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();               
        return configurationInfo.getGlEsVersion();
    } else {
        return GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_VERSION);
    }
}
```

Be aware, though, that this might not work for *all* versions and you might need to split the method into more cases or change the min SDK_INT used for the comparison (I suspect for example that for Honeycomb it already needs the first method, but have not tested it).

Comment: I have tried GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_VERSION), GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION), GLES10.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION),  
GLES20.glGetString(GL10.GL_VERSION), GLES10.glGetString(GL10.GL_VERSION),  
I have tried GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_VERSION), GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION), GL10.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION) and several others for GL ES 2.0 but it always returns null.

Comment: In your original post you imply that it was working for you. If it's not the case, please make it clear in the question.

Comment: configurationInfo.getGlEsVersion(); is just a check and it is returning the the correct information. i.e the version of the GL. Still GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION), returns null for 2.3.6.